# redirect onclick of table row in grails

Tags: grails, redirect

I have table in UI which is populated by values from database. Now I want to call a controller action Onclick of table row and render to different view.
I tried following code function is getting executed properly but its not rendering to different view.

**In GSP:**

```
 <tr onclick="<g:remoteFunction controller="LeaveApplied" action='getLeaveDetail' id='${it.id}'/>">
```

controller:

```
def getLeaveDetails(){
    def leaveObj = leaveAppliedService.getLeaveDetail(params.id)
    println "leave: "+leaveObj
    render(view:'respond', model: [leave:leaveObj])
     }
```

Any Answers will be thank full.

Comment: Note your action in the remoteFunction is `getLeaveDetail` and your action name is `getLeaveDetailS`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update your table with an ajax call, you can try this:

GSP:

```
onclick="<g:remoteFunction controller="LeaveApplied" action="getLeaveDetail" params="[id: it.id]" update="target_div" />"
```

Controller:

```
def getLeaveDetails(){
   def leaveObj = leaveAppliedService.getLeaveDetail(params.id)
   render(template:'respond', model: [leave:leaveObj])
 }
```

Haven't tested the code, but the important things are to set the `params` and `update` Attributes in your GSP and to render a template instead of a view.